# Cannot group datapoints by cluster

Tags: python, list, cluster-analysis

I have a datalists where each datapoint has 5 features and a cluster assigned to each point. 
You can see the beginning of it here, last column is the cluster number:

```
[[4.01682810e-01 2.14628527e-02 2.99529665e-02 2.79935965e-01 9.21441137e-01 9.00000000e+00]
[9.32087200e-03 3.38196129e-01 8.49571569e-01 3.69402590e-01 1.92096835e-01 1.20000000e+01]
[7.51465196e-01 4.45955645e-01 3.37174838e-01 3.65047097e-01 5.81725084e-01 1.00000000e+00]
```

I want to create a list of lists of datapoints of the same cluster, so I wrote the following function and tried to execute it:

```
def returnArrayOfClusters(data, clusterNumbers):
    # create an empty column
    column = []
    # create an empty list we want to output
    listOfClusters = []
    # fill it with a column for each cluster
    for i in clusterNumbers:
        listOfClusters.append(column)
    print(listOfClusters)
    ## fill the columns with points according to their cluster
    for datapoint in data:
        print(datapoint)
        cluster = int(datapoint[5])
        listOfClusters[cluster].append(datapoint)
    return listOfClusters

listOfClusters = returnArrayOfClusters(data_labeled_unfinished, range(0,14))
```

What I get is an unordered list of datapoints of this format (the end of the list), and as you can see all the points in the column are of different clusters (they have different last value):

```
array([ 0.81802695,  0.45533606,  0.33799001,  0.26154893,  0.64155249,
13.        ]), array([0.12995366, 0.45586338, 0.85833814, 0.32153188, 0.28736836,
1.        ]), array([0.06230581, 0.47400143, 0.78671841, 0.3162376 , 0.04819034,
9.        ]), array([0.15291747, 0.54247295, 0.54407916, 0.87888682, 0.46639597,
8.        ]), array([ 0.21578994,  0.178303  ,  0.80642112,  0.39853499,  0.27832876,
10.        ]), array([0.27426491, 0.32986967, 0.49411613, 0.50818875, 0.2336591 ,
5.        ])]
```

Maybe it is a very stupid mistake, but I just cannot spot the error.
What I expect to see, however, is to be all the points in the list to be of the same cluster (i.e. in the output have the same value of the 6th item)

Comment: Can you edit your question and put there desired output as well?

Comment: Looking at your code `listOfClusters.append(column)` looks fishy - the `column` points to same list. Maybe `listOfClusters.append([])` is correct way?

Comment: @Andrej Kesely I did that to create a list of empty lists so that there's an empty list for every cluster. At the end I want a list of lists, where each 2nd layer list contains datapoints belonging to the same cluster (the same 6th item value).
Indeed, when I try this function on my dataset, it prints listOfClusters as 
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []] 
The problem is that I cannot properly fill each of these empty lists inside the main list with the appropriate datapoints. 

Hope I made it clear

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I got you correct, you can split your data using a list comprehension, for example:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np
X = np.random.normal(0,1,(100,5))
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=8, random_state=0).fit(X)
data = np.concatenate((X,kmeans.labels_.reshape(-1,1)),axis=1)

[data[data[:,5]==i,] for i in np.unique(data[:,5])]
```

in your case:

```
[data_labeled_unfinished[data_labeled_unfinished[:,5]==i,] for i in np.unique(data_labeled_unfinished[:,5])]
```